# C++ _popen() windows leaks paged pool memory

Tags: c++, windows, memory-leaks, pool

Main application runs in Windows service and that process starts other c++ console processes but all console modes are hidden, i.e. parent process is Windows Service and child processes are non-console applications.

Observed **paged pool** memory of the system is increasing during call _popen() on the customer system windows server 2016. The application runs clean on our lab system same OS.

From the Windows Performance tool xperf, captured the logs and check the call stack.
attached the pic for reference.

[image: _popen call stack]

```
void CMachine::GetJavaVersion()
{
m_stJavaVersion.m_strName = " Java version";

CPUChar strVersion[64] = { 0 };
BOOL bFound = CheckJREVersion(strVersion, 64);

BYTE bytColorSt = RED;
string strRemark;

FILE *fp = NULL;
char version[130] = { 0 };
BOOL bFoundVersion = FALSE;
fp = _popen("java -version 2>&1", "r");
while (fp && fgets(version, sizeof version, fp))
{
    string strTmp = version;
    if (strTmp.find("version") != string::npos)
    {
        bFoundVersion = TRUE;
        break;
    }
}
if(fp) _pclose(fp);

....
```

PoolMon trace

Memory:33401164K Avail:30057324K  PageFlts: 92362   InRam Krnl:20212K P:776328K
Commit:3228052K Limit:37595468K Peak:4747992K            Pool N:182820K P:782568K
System pool information
Tag  Type     Allocs            Frees            Diff       Bytes                  Per Alloc

Toke Paged  10546816 ( 390)  10319712 ( 382)   227104   324868080 (      11392)        1430
CM31 Paged     42886 (   0)     20849 (   0)    22037   101154816 (          0)        4590
SeAt Paged  44678436 (1662)  43769798 (1630)   908638    87253680 (       3072)          96
QINi Paged       234 (   0)         1 (   0)      233    60293216 (          0)      258769
MmSt Paged   2683066 (  79)   2670922 (  83)    12144    27223856 (       3312)        2241

[PoolMon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cNSH.png)

Comment: Usually a memory leak involving resource acquisition (such as a call to `_popen`) comes from a failure to release that resource (i.e. a corresponding call to `_pclose`). Did you try to reduce your code to a small program that just calls _popen/_pclose?

Comment: Another thing I've found is that some bugs only appear when you run your application at scale. When it "runs clean" in your lab, how big is the input data sample compared to your customer's full data?

Comment: _popen() spawns command prompt to get installed java version information on timer of 30 secs. Also from logs observed that FILE pointer is valid to get close

Comment: I wonder if the Java sub process never exits on the customer’s machine?  That could cause your fgets() call to never return, and therefore _pclose() never gets called.  Perhaps the customer’s Java.exe is broken somehow, or another program named Java.exe is in the command-path and getting executed instead?

Comment: BTW: if the output of "version" is cut in the middle by the 130 char buffer, you'll not find it.

Comment: I just thought of this: Are you and the customer getting the same Java version out of this?

Answer (score 1):

Eric Lippert writes about [benchmark mistakes](https://ericlippert.com/2013/05/14/benchmarking-mistakes-part-one/). I think mistake #1 applies to your case:

> Mistake #1: Choosing a bad metric.

Why do you measure "paged pool" to determine a memory leak?

Paged memory is the memory that is swapped out to disk. This happens because the physical RAM is needed for something else. What is the physical RAM needed for? Probably for running the process that you start.

Once the memory is swapped to disk, it may take a while until it is swapped back to RAM. That will happen just when some other application tries to access the memory - and that may be minutes, if ever.

I also tend to say that memory isn't leaked *during* a method call but *after* a method call. After the method call, all variables should be destroyed and the related resources should be released.

---

If you are told that the paged pool is the cause, then ask for proof.

On my Windows 10 system, the paged pool limit is 17 GB. This can be shown by Process Explorer in View/System Information with Symbols configured.

[image: Process Explorer Paged Pool Limit]

If you're running `java -version` so often that it leaks 17 GB of kernel memory, then something is seriously wrong. Of course there will be a pipe or something to redirect the output from Java to your application so you can read the stream. There will also be other kernel objects like a process, a thread etc.

Even with 1 kB of kernel memory leak for each call, you would need to call that 17 million times to exhaust the paged pool. If that's the case, maybe you should consider caching the result anyway. It should be unlikely that server admins install and uninstall Java 17 million times in a few days.

For monitoring the paged pool, you can try [Poolmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/poolmon) with [`/p /P` command line parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/poolmon-startup-command). Poolmon is part of the [WDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk).

---

Problems in your code:

Your code has at least 2 problems:

1. if "version" never appears in the output, your code might run in an endless loop. How could that happen? It's unlikely, but if I rename my HelloWorld.exe to java.exe, it could.
2. if "version" appears in the output but accidentally "ver" is in the first buffer and "sion" is in the second buffer, you'll never find out it actually was there. Your code could run into an endless loop.

Comment: One has to assume that it was the customer who noticed this and called to complain.  Now, how do you explain this to the customer?

Comment: @Spencer: customers use wrong metrics all the time. Best example is using Windows Task Manager and complaining about too much "Working Set Size". My recommendation then is: remove RAM and it will become lower.

Comment: @Spencer: often it's good to give an example which doesn't involve your app at all, e.g. run Word or any other application that has not run before. Does that increase page pool as well? See?

Comment: Or maybe just KISS: Say "Don't worry about that.  Watch X instead."

Comment: When the system (Windows Server 2016) is Idle or without our application installed, the system's memory is stable. But the same system with our application installed and run, memory leaks at regular interval i.e with timer and at last the server reboots as there is no memory for the application to run.

Comment: we noticed that paged pool memory is exhausting because the server rebooted after some days with our application running. In my understanding paged pool memory also utilized for token objects i.e pipe().

Comment: @ShamiShariff That information should definitely be in the question